# Help with differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation using Mathematica:

`DSolve[y'[x] == 3/4 (2 - (3 + 2 E^(3 x))/(1 + E^(3 x) - 2 E^(6 x) - 2 E^(6 y[x]))),  y[x], x]`

and I am getting the following error

`Solve: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.`

This message suggests that Mathematica is able to do part of the integration. However, after a little while, Mathematica just prints the equation I started with.

Is there a way to see exactly at which point Mathematica decided to stop the calculation?

Comment: Is `NDSolve` not adequate to your needs?

Comment: **This message suggests that Mathematica is able to do part of the integration** I do not know where this message `Inverse functions are being used by Solve` is coming from. I tried to do Trace but output was so large Mathematica hanged when trying to display it all. This ode has no analytical solution. So I doubt very much that Mathematica was able to get to the stage where where it just need to solve some equation to obtain the final solution.  May be this message was thrown by error somewhere along the computation path? Or when it was trying something. It does not necessarily mean much.

Comment: I suspect Mathematica is attempting to eliminate the dependent variable.  Letting y'=p and solving for y results in an expression in terms of Log:  $$ y\to \fbox{$\frac{1}{6} \left(2 i \pi  c_1+\log \left(-\frac{-4 e^{3 x} p+8 e^{6 x} p-4 p-12 e^{6 x}-3}{4 (2 p-3)}\right)\right)\text{ if }c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$} $$  This expression is of course multi-valued.

Answer (score -1):

Mathematica will do the obvious substitution of the exponential, since there exists no other solution strategy for such serverely  non-linear equation

```
DSolve[y'[x] == 
  3/4 (2 - (3 + 2 E^(3 x) ))/(1 + E^(3 x) - 2 E^(6 x) - 2 (E^(6 y)) ),
       y[x], x]

In[33]:= dy/dx == 3/4 (2 - (3 + 2 E^(3 x) ))/
            (1 + E^(3 x) - 2 E^(6 x) - 2 (E^(6 y)) ) /. 
               {6 y -> Log[u],  dy -> 1/6 du/u}

Out[33]= du/(6 dx u) == (3 (-1 - 2 E^(3 x)))/(4 (1 + E^(3 x) - 2 E^(6 x) - 2 u))

In[35]:= DSolve[u'[x] == (9 (-1 - 2 E^(3 x)) u[x])/
(2 (1 + E^(3 x) - 2 E^(6 x) - 2 u[x])), u, x]

Out[35]= $Aborted
```

.... after 10 Minutes

Comment: My point is that Mathematica is clearly able to reach a point of being able to use Solve. I would like to know what is the expression that is left before it attempts to use solve.

Comment: The internal representation of the intermediate state is likely extremely complicated and not in natural "human interpretable" form.  I don't think it would help you.

Comment: The Tracing only shows a library search, that cannot be traced. In theory, there are few types of  linear  ODE'S of the second order, with non-constant coefficients, that can be solved by quadratures. Then there is the class of physical equations that are solved by table lookups.  Its   a non-economical  path of solution detection by transforming the unknown,  dependent function by a transformation, as I did it. There exists simply no concept to find such a transformation. In the history of ODE's, solvable  forms of eqautions were always found in models, that suggested the transform.